# Power Bi : Failed to update data source credentials: 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, powerbi-gateway

I wanted to schedule refresh of my power bi reports. My database server is running on port 5432. I have installed Power Bi gateway personal mode. So while doing this in option called Data Source Credentials while editing credentials even after entering correct server name (localhost), database name (ovanteprod) and user/password I'm getting this error.

[image: Error as shown here]

Is this something related with firewall or power bi gateway personal mode? If yes what is solution.

I have changed inbound and outbound rules for port 5432. But still this is not working.

Comment: Sounds like a network problem, like `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` or a firewall or something similar.